# behat step "I should see" does not see

Tags: yii, behat

Using Behat in Yii framework, I am observing its quite strange behaviour: Behat does not find some text when using steps like

```
Then I should see "some text"
```

Some text it finds normaly, but some - not. To be sure that I am on the page I think I am on, I've added sort of markers in the view files and Behat sees them.

So, the scenario is

```
  Scenario: editing journal
    Given the following journals are present:
        | name          | link                      | description           |
        | Murzilka      | http://www.murz.com       | advanced child journal| 
        | Nature        | www nature com            | nice journal          |
    When I am on edit page for journal "Nature"
    Then I should see "Update Nature"
    Then I should see "nice journal"
    Then I should see "1qazxsw2" <-- a marker
    Then I should see "2wsxcde3" <-- a marker
    Then I should see "www nature com"
```

The output is then

```
 Scenario: editing journal
   # features\journal.feature:21
Given the following journals are present:
   # FeatureContext::theFollowingJournalsArePresent()
  | name     | link                | description            |
  | Murzilka | http://www.murz.com | advanced child journal |
  | Nature   | www nature com      | nice journal           |
When I am on edit page for journal "Nature"
   # FeatureContext::iAmOnEditPageForJournal()
Then I should see "Update Nature"
   # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
Then I should see "nice journal"
   # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
Then I should see "1qazxsw2"
   # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
Then I should see "2wsxcde3"
   # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
Then I should see "www nature com"
   # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
  The text "www nature com" was not found anywhere in the text of the current page.
```

The strange is that if I go to the page (in test environment), I see all those phrases including "www nature com".

Comment: I had this problem too because my site wasn't returning encoding header. Can that be your problem too?

Comment: I don't know. I've got `<meta charset="utf-8" />` and in fact I do not use any special symbols.

Answer (score 3):

The problem sporadically appears when the step "Then I should see ..." refers to the text in an input field. I've found out that for this purpose there is a predefined step

```
Then /^the "(?P<field>(?:[^"]|\\")*)" field should contain "(?P<value>(?:[^"]|\\")*)"$/
    - Checks, that form field with specified id|name|label|value has specified value.
    # FeatureContext::assertFieldContains()
```

which is supposed to be used like this:

```
Then the "journal[name]" field should contain "nice journal"
```

With this modification, Behat finds all phrases.

Comment: Worked for me! Did you add the `[name]` for context or because it was required with that version of behat? I did not need it and if it's just for context I was kinda confused. Can you mark this as the answer as well?