# Behat "I should see" function doesn't detect the links

Tags: javascript, testing, moodle, behat, gherkin

I'm trying to do a search up on the admin block for Moodle. However, when I use "press 'Search'" and I use the "I should see" function, the function doesn't detect the content even though it's there.

Can you please, help me out?

This is somewhat similar to this one --> [behat step "I should see" does not see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599932/behat-step-i-should-see-does-not-see)

```
Then I fill the moodle form with:
        | realname | ajones |
      And I check "U"
      And I press "Search"
      #And I should see "alice jones"
      And I am on homepage
      Then I fill the moodle form with:
        | realname | jo |
      And I check "U"
      And I press "Search"
      #And I should see "bob jones"
      #And I should see "alice jones"
      #And I should see "jon stewart"

      And I am on homepage 
      Then I fill the moodle form with:
        | realname | alice |
      And I check "U"
      And I press "Search"
      #Then I should see "No users found"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wait for the page to load first.

The trick is to wait until the text becomes available. I can't remember the exact code but if you go to this link

http://docs.behat.org/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html

and search for this

$this->getSession()->wait(

You will find this

```
/**
 * @Then /^I wait for the suggestion box to appear$/
 */
public function iWaitForTheSuggestionBoxToAppear()
{
    $this->getSession()->wait(5000,
        "$('.suggestions-results').children().length > 0"
    );
}
```

This will wait 5 seconds until the suggestions-results appears. I remember writing something similar to wait for text but I haven't got access to the code.

Comment: It's kinda weird because when I tried to use the "I should see" function to lookup for the header tags (without using the delay), it worked. However, when it comes to the links it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

I use this custom step to check for links

```
/**
     * @Given /^a link to "([^"]*)" should exist$/
     */
    public function aLinkToShouldExist($url) {
        return new Then ( "I should see an \"a[href='$url']\" element" );
    }
```

and in $url I literally put my link address. but you should edit your post and put your code to see what is the problem